# Why letsencrypt showing error?

Tags: ssl, ubuntu-14.04, lets-encrypt

I am trying to install letsencrypt on ubuntu 14 on DigitalOcean Server but getting this issue.

[image]

I tried sudo to install but same error, also try to install libs but nothing happen.

apt-key update result :

```
gpg: key 437D05B5: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: key FBB75451: "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: key C0B21F32: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: key EFE21092: "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 4
gpg:              unchanged: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install (or update) the public key(s) used to verify the packages.

Do this:

```
apt-key update
apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find answer here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/102153/untrusted-package-errors-after-installing-security-tools

But easy thing just use these commands :

```
apt-get autoclean
apt-get --purge autoremove
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This may solve your issue or look into link.

Comment: Thanks, setup started work but asking for this :  No names were found in your configuration files.  You should specify ServerNames in your config files in order to allow for accurate installation of your certificate.

Comment: Sorry i can't help you here with this comment only.

Comment: Check this article... it might help: https://www.attosol.com/implementing-ssl-free-quick/