# Letsencrypt installation fails in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, lets-encrypt

`sudo apt-get install letsencrypt`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
` letsencrypt : Depends: python-letsencrypt (= 0.4.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python:any (>= 2.7~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why letsencrypt showing error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37156021/why-letsencrypt-showing-error)

Comment: @anandtripathi it's a different issue

Answer (score 1):

Remove the python package from ubuntu
and install python-dev

`sudo apt-get remove python`

`sudo apt-get install python-dev`

This should solve the letsencrypt installation

Comment: I strongly advise not to run `sudo apt-get remove python`. It will remove all packages depending on Python, which can be quite a lot.

Comment: @KlausD. We got this error on fresh ubuntu16.04 after node.js installation. So we didnt had much dependencies on python